# How to process rtf files on R?

Tags: r

I have huge number of *.rtf (rich text format) files. They contain text data to be analysed. But R does not seem to support them. When I run the code I get garbage values. The code is right but the word format doesn't seem to be very well supported. Is there any easier method to get the code running on them because converting them to *.txt file is an option that I hesitate to take due to the fact that there are more than 1000 files! I am using Windows operating system.

Comment: Google for "windows batch rtf to text" and pick a non-malware-ridden utility to convert the RTF files to UTF-8 or ASCII files. It's a horrible idea to use wordpad to create any programming language source file, esp with free alternatives like Notepad++ & SublimeText out there.

Comment: As of October 2018, there are `textreadr` and `striprtf` that can handle this job quite decently.